# Symfony 3 - CKEditor doesn't work anymore

Tags: php, symfony, ckeditor

I just noticed that my CKEditor does not work anymore. It had been a few days since I had not been to the page that uses CKEditor on my site.
But the facts are there. I only have a simple Textaera instead of the CKEditor tool.

Is there a way to see where the problem comes from?

**My AppKernel.php:**

```
$bundles = [
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
            new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
            new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
            new AppBundle\AppBundle(),
            new Site\PagesBundle\PagesBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
            new Stof\DoctrineExtensionsBundle\StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle(),
            new Vich\UploaderBundle\VichUploaderBundle(),
            new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
            new FOS\CKEditorBundle\FOSCKEditorBundle(),
            new Besancon\AuthBundle\BesanconAuthBundle(),
            new JMS\SerializerBundle\JMSSerializerBundle(),
        ];
```

**A part of my config.yml:**

```
fos_ck_editor:
    configs:
        my_config:
            toolbar: [ ["Source", "-", "Save"], "/", ["Anchor"], "/", ["Maximize"] ]
            uiColor:                "#000000"
```

**The formType :**

```
<?php

namespace Site\PagesBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use FOS\CKEditorBundle\Form\Type\CKEditorType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\RangeType;

class InformationType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
        ->add('titre',TextType::class,array(
            'attr' => array(
                'placeholder'=> 'Titre de l\'information',
                'class'=>'form-control'
            )
        ))
        ->add('contenu', CKEditorType::class, array(
            'config' => array(
                'uiColor' => '#ffffff',
                'toolbar'=>'full'
            ),))
        ->add('zone',ChoiceType::class, array(
            'choices'=> array(
                'Zone 1'=>'Zone 1',
                'Zone 2'=>'Zone 2',
                'Zone 3'=>'Zone 3',

            ),
        ))
        ->add('criticite', RangeType::class, array(
            'label'=> 'Taux de criticité',
            'attr'=>array(
                'list'=> 'tauxCriticite'
            )
        ))
        ;
    }
```

**And the twig file :**

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}


{% block body %}
    <h1>Information creation</h1>

    {{ form_start(form) }}

        {{form_row (form.titre)}}

        {{form_row (form.zone)}}

        {{form_row (form.contenu)}}

        {{form_row (form.criticite)}}
        <datalist id="tauxCriticite">
            <option value="0" label="0%">
            <option value="10">
            <option value="20">
            <option value="30">
            <option value="40">
            <option label="50" value="50">
            <option value="60">
            <option value="70">
            <option value="80">
            <option value="90">
            <option value="100" label="100%">
          </datalist>

          <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Ajouter"/>
          <a href="{{path('informations_index')}}" class="btn btn-primary">Retour</a>
    {{ form_end(form) }}

{% endblock %}
```

So, we agree that it's not a configuration problem ?

EDIT : I also add the fact that I have the ckeditor bundle in my bundle, and that I also have the ckeditor folder in the "web" folder

Comment: Are you sure ckeditor's css and javascript assets are included in your template ?

Comment: See also here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56270227/symfony-3-ckeditor-not-correctly-installed-in-prod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56270227/symfony-3-ckeditor-not-correctly-installed-in-prod)