# Symfony 3 - CKEditor not correctly installed in PROD

Tags: php, symfony, ckeditor, installation, assets

on my site, I have the CKEditor bundle installed. It worked in PREPROD. But by switching to PROD, CKEditor does not work anymore. It is installed however, can someone please help me?

I've :

```
/web/ckeditor
/web/bundle/pages/ckeditor
/src/Site/PagesBundle/Resources/Public/ckeditor
```

But nothing is working.
And if i try this :

> php bin/console ckeditor:install

I've

In CKEditorInstaller.php line 334:

Unable to download CKEditor ZIP archive from "https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-releases/archive/full/latest.zip". (file_get_contents(https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-releases/archive/full/latest.zip): failed to open s
  tream: Connection timed out)

Comment: Please make sure that your fire wall isn't blocking the connection because from what I have checked the file is available under the link. There was a similar issue https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/issues/1280 which turned out to be openssl library problem.

Answer (score 4):

if you have all the files and you are using fos ckeditor, please check that you have this code under `twig.form_themes` :

```
# Symfony 2/3: app/config/config.yml
# Symfony 4: config/packages/twig.yaml

twig:
    form_themes:
         - '@FOSCKEditor/Form/ckeditor_widget.html.twig'
```

Comment: AFter upgrading an SF 2.4 to 2.8 to 3.4, getting ckeditor to work properly was the last piece. This obscure / undocumented solution was the missing piece. Thank you!